# How to goto next textfield when using one common textfield for all textfield?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitextfield

I have placed one UITextField in storyboard within tableview, and create multiple textfield (4 nos.) using code.

my issue is I cannot goto 2nd uitextfield when press return key on keyboard. I have use below code, in tableview cell

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    let nextTag: NSInteger = textField.tag + 1

    let nextResponder: UIResponder = textField.superview!.viewWithTag(nextTag)!
    if (nextResponder != nil) {

        nextResponder.becomeFirstResponder()
    } else {
      
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
    }
    return false 
}
```

Comment: did you check tags of UItextfield of your table view in attribute inspector ?

Comment: You say *"... within tableview, and create multiple textfield (4 nos.) ..."* -- So, do you mean you have a `UITextField` in a cell, and you have **4 rows** in your table? Or, do you mean you have 4 `UITextField`s in a **single cell**?

Comment: @DonMag I have place one textfield on a tableview cell using storyboard and create 4 rows and add that textfield there.

Comment: *"... tableview cell using storyboard and create 4 rows ..."* -- OK, that's your problem. In your code: `textField.superview!.viewWithTag(nextTag)!`, `textField.superview` is *that cell's* `contentView`. So, it will not find a different view in a different cell. You should probably use a closure so your code can tell the tableView **controller** to set the next row's text field to first responder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First set the textField tag with current row in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` methods.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MyCell", for: indexPath) as! MyCell
        
        cell.textField.tag = indexPath.row

    return cell
    }
```

After that get the next cell in `textFieldShouldReturn` method and set the next cell textField `firstResponder`.

```
    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    let nexttag = textField.tag + 1
    if nexttag < tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: 0) {
        let nextIndexPath = IndexPath(row: nexttag, section: 0)
        if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: nextIndexPath) as? MyCell{
            cell.textfield.becomeFirstResponder()
            tableView.scrollToRow(at: nextIndexPath, at: .none, animated: true)
        }
    } else {
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
    }
    return false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 4 rows in your table, where each cell has a `UITextField`.

So this code you're trying to use:

```
textField.superview!.viewWithTag(nextTag)!
```

won't work, because `textField.superview` is the `contentView` of the cell that holds that text field.

One approach is to use a closure that allows your cell to tell the controller that the user tapped Return, and then let the controller handle setting the next row's text field to first responder.

Here is a very simple example of how you might want to implement this:

```
class ResponderCell: UITableViewCell, UITextFieldDelegate {
    
    @IBOutlet var textField: UITextField!
    
    var returnClosure: ((String, UITableViewCell)->())?
    
    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        
        // tell our table view controller
        returnClosure?(textField.text ?? "", self)
        
        return false

    }
    
}

class ResponderTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    var myData: [String] = [
        "One",
        "Two",
        "Three",
        "Four",
    ]
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return myData.count
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let c = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "rCell", for: indexPath) as! ResponderCell
        
        c.textField.text = myData[indexPath.row]
        
        c.returnClosure = { [weak self, weak tableView] str, c in
            // make sure we're safely accessing these objects
            guard let self = self,
                  let tableView = tableView,
                  let pth = tableView.indexPath(for: c)
            else {
                return
            }

            // update data array with textField's text
            self.myData[pth.row] = str

            // increment the row
            let nextIndexPath = IndexPath(row: pth.row + 1, section: pth.section)

            // if we can get the next cell...
            if let nextCell = self.tableView.cellForRow(at: nextIndexPath) as? ResponderCell {
                // set it's textField to first responder
                nextCell.textField.becomeFirstResponder()
            }
        }

        return c
    }
    
}
```

Comment: That's works,
can you tell me how we can do that using Rxswift?